# Get Azure Linux Virtual Machine Guest OS memory metrics

Tags: azure, metrics, ubuntu-18.04, azure-monitoring, azure-gov

I have an Ubuntu Linux Virtual Machine in Azure Government that I am trying to get metrics from the guest operating system.  I have enabled Linux Diagnostics Agent 3.0 extension and guest OS level monitoring.

1. Is there a way to get VM guest OS metrics to the Monitor metric without using Log Analytics?
2. Is there any other Linux OS configurations I have to change in order to get these types of metrics?

Has anyone have gotten this to work in Azure Government if so please let me know the steps you took to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the first question as written. Are you asking if there's a way to get the metrics into Azure Monitor?

Are there specific diagnostics you're looking to enable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Tegraf agent. Linux diagnostics agent cant not be set to send metrics to AZ monitor.
 It works in non-gov.